# UITextField in a UIScollView causing scrolling issues

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I have a heavily customized UITextField in a UIScrollView. When the user enters a character into the textfield I am calculating where I want the contentOffset of the scrollview and I'm setting it. That works fine after the first character is entered, the scroll view goes where its supposed to.

After the next character is entered I set the offset again to the same point but for some reason, when the redraw occurs, it resets the offset back to 0,0. Setting the offset a third time works and then after a forth character is entered it resets back to 0,0. The net affect is that the scrollview bounces back and forth between the offset I want and 0,0 after each character is entered.

I've verified that I'm setting the offset to the same point each time and that I'm not resetting the offset anywhere else in my code.

This issue has been driving me crazy so any direction regarding what this could be or how to debug it would really be appreciated.

Comment: it may help to post relevant code for others to debug, otherwise all people can do is speculate.

Comment: can you post some portion of code so we can help you what's wrong there ? otherwise we can't figure out.

Comment: I see that you haven't accepted any answers. If you found my answer to be helpful, you should accept it and if you didn't you should leave a comment to let me know why.

Comment: I was going to post the code but in the process realized there was a lot of relevant code spread across many files so I opted not to. I was able to figure out a somewhat hacky workaround, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, without any code there is a limit to what we can do. However, I think there might be a rather simple solution to your problem. Before setting the content offset check the current content offset and if it's already correct don't bother resetting it.

Comment: Erik, apologies. Unfortunately this did not work for me. I figured out a work around on my own which is why I haven't accepted this answer.